# Multi line text in Kv Language

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I want to add multi line text to one of my screens, as a Label. In python, usually you just use the \n, but in kv, I have no idea how to do it. How do I make text multiline when using Kv Language?

```
Builder.load_string("""
<MenuScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: "vertical"
        Button:
            text: "About Casa Da Música"
            on_press: root.manager.current = "about"
        Button:
            text: "Images"
            on_press: root.manager.current = "images"
<AboutScreen>:
    BoxLayout:
        Label:
            size: self.texture_size
            text: 'textmulti' #I want to put 'text' and 'multi' in separate lines
        Button:
            text: "Go back to Main Menu"
            on_press: root.manager.current = "menu"
<ImagesScreen>
    GridLayout:
        cols: 2
        Image:
            allow_stretch: True
            source: '/Users/alexandresilva/casa_da_musica/app/Casamusicaexterior.jpg'
        Image:
            allow_stretch: True
            source: '/Users/alexandresilva/casa_da_musica/app/1280x720_303779.jpg'
        Image:
            allow_stretch: True
            source: '/Users/alexandresilva/casa_da_musica/app/5076446.jpg'
        Image:
            allow_stretch: True
            source: '/Users/alexandresilva/casa_da_musica/app/ImageGen.ashx-2.jpeg'
        Image:
            allow_stretch: True
            source: '/Users/alexandresilva/casa_da_musica/app/ImageGen.ashx-6.jpeg'
        Button:
            text: "Go back to Main Menu"
            on_press: root.manager.current = "menu"
<ConcertosScreen>
    
""")
```

Thanks, everyone!

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I just need to use double instead of single slash.

Comment: The right part of a kivy property (right side of the `:`, the value) is pure Python. If something works in Python , it works there too..